# Maximum likelihood estimator - Uniform distribution

Tags: statistics, estimation, maximum-likelihood

**Let X have an uniform distribution on the segment [a,b]. With the method of maximum likelihood, estimate the parameter d = b-a. Then check if the estimator is consistent.**

Hi, i tried solving this problem. I don't know how to continue. Any help will be welcomed :) 
Thanks in advance

Starting form:

$$f_x(x)= \begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{\theta} , x \in [a,b] \\ 0, otherwise 
\end{cases}$$

$$L(\theta) = (\frac{1}{\theta}) ^n$$
$$\frac{\partial{\ln(L(\theta))}}{\partial{\theta}} = \frac{\partial\ln(\frac{1}{\theta}) ^n}{\theta}=0$$ 
after solving this i have $$\frac{-n}{\theta}=0$$

Comment: Math mode isn't intended for italicizing text; as you can see here, it yields the wrong spacing for that. Usually text is italicized by enclosing it in asterisks. If you want to italicize text within math mode, you can use `\mathit{...}`. In the present case, there doesn't seem to be a need to italicize the text; in that case you can use `\text{...}` to include roman text in math mode. You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Differentiation is just wrong. If you have a sample of $n$ observations, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/233778/321264.

Comment: Very similar to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/649678/418542) and linked ones as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case in which you have to find the maximum
of the likelihood curve by logic, not by differentiation. (This often happens when the parameter of interest determines the interval of support
of the distribution.)

Recall that the likelihood function is the density function viewed as a function of the parameter (here $d)$ for an
observed value of the random variable (here $X = 25).$

The graph is made using R statistical software, where
`dunif` is a uniform density function.

```
x = 25;  a = 20;  d = seq(.01, 40, by=0.01)
like = dunif(x, a, a+d)
plot(d, like, type="l", lwd=2)
abline(h = 0, col="green2")
```

[image]

Thus the MLE of $d$ is $X - a = 25 - 20 = 5.$

*Note:* The height of the likelihood function
is maximized by making the interval of support
of the distribution as short as possible.